# PowerBI-JavaScript: How to programmatically clear filtering triggered by a connected visual?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have two visuals (two tables) which are connected to each other. So selecting a row in one table is respectively filtering another table. At some point of time I want to hide the first table and cancel respective filtering on the another table. I'm hiding visual by changing custom layout and updating report settings. However after table becomes hidden the filtering triggered by it is still kept. I investigated getFilters() response of all levels: report, page, visuals but it doesn't contain any information about filtering triggered by another connected visual so setFilters(...) will not work. Is it possible to programmatically clear filtering triggered by a connected visual using PowerBI-JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, this capability is not supported in PowerBI-Javascript library.

For more info check out the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters#visual-level-filters).

Comment: I'm wondering if it is planned to be implemented sometime? Looks like a critical functionality.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation we found out that this problem can be resolved using bookmarks. We need to create 2 bookmarks - the 1st should contain all visuals and the 2nd should contain only one visual which is left when the other visual is hidden. And then before updating settings with custom layout we also need to apply respective bookmark.